# Java. Socket. IO. Помогите найти ошибку в клиент серверном приложении

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

Приложение должно отравлять файл с клиента на сервер. Но оно зависает в цикле чтения на стороне сервера. Помогите пожалуйста найти проблему, а то я что-то совсем приуныл...
Вот код:

Сервер:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();

        server.initServerSocket();
        server.initSocket();
        server.download("root.txt");
    }

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    private void initServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5213);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initSocket() {
        try {
            this.socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void download(String nameFile) {
        try (InputStream input = this.socket.getInputStream()){
            // available() - возвращает колличество сейчас доступных байтов
            byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
            // читаем
            int i = input.read(buffer);
            while (i != -1) {
                System.out.println("1.6"); // ВОТ ТУТ НЕ ВЫХОДИТ ИЗ ЦИКЛА
                i = input.read(buffer);
            }
            this.createFile(nameFile,buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean createFile(String nameFile, byte[] buffer) {
        File file = new File(format("%s/%s",Paths.REPO.getPath(),nameFile));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                System.out.println("1.8");
                out.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return file.exists();
    }
}
```

И вот клиент:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 5213;
        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        Client client = new Client();
        client.initSocket(address,port);
        client.upload("/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/client/root.txt");

    }

    private Socket socket;

    private void initSocket(String address, int port) {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(address, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void upload(String path) {
        try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
             FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
             BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn)) {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) new File(path).length()];
            buffer.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, потому что input.read возвращает 0 - "нет больше данных для чтения". -1 он возвращает когда InputStream больше не доступен (закрыт).

```
while (i != -1) {
   System.out.println("1.6"); // ВОТ ТУТ НЕ ВЫХОДИТ ИЗ ЦИКЛА
   i = input.read(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек. Второй день совокупляюсь с этой проблемой. На конец-то решил!